# Defining game objects and they're collider in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make a color switch replica in unity, I have a circle which is made of 4 quarter circles tagged red,blue,yellow and green.
But I have problem defining they're collider.
Code looks like this:

```
    public gameObject Red;
    public gameObject Blue;
    public gameObject Green;
    public gameObject Yellow;

void Start()
    {
        Red = FindGameObjectWithTag("Red");
        Blue = FindGameObjectWithTag("Blue");
        Green = FindGameObjectWithTag("Green");
        Yellow = FindGameObjectWithTag("Yellow");
    }
```

Now if I want to use they're collider should I define collider for each of them or not?
like this :

```
    Collider RCollider;
    Collider BCollider;
    Collider GCollider;
    Collider YCollider;

    ...

        RCollider = Red.Getcomponent<>();
        BCollider = Blue.Getcomponent<>();
        GCollider = Green.Getcomponent<>();
        YCollider = Yellow.Getcomponent<>();
```

I think my problem is in the difference between GameObject and gameObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues, the first one is that you're using `gameObject` which is a property while you should be using `GameObject` which is a class, so your code should look like this

```
public GameObject Red;
public GameObject Blue;
// etc...
```

Your second problem is that you're not defining what component you want to get in `GetComponent`, in this case it would be the `Collider` component so your code should look like this:

```
RCollider = Red.Getcomponent<Collider>();
BCollider = Blue.Getcomponent<Collider>();
```

Edit:
I also noticed you're using `FindGameObjectWithTag();` which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist, you need to use `FindGameObjectsWithTag();` which will return a list of `GameObjects` with that tag, in your case if there is only one of each you would write

```
void Start()
    {
        Red = FindGameObjectsWithTag("Red")[0];
        Blue = FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blue")[0];
        Green = FindGameObjectsWithTag("Green")[0];
        Yellow = FindGameObjectsWithTag("Yellow")[0];
    }
```